# Solving second order circuits by introducing a new voltage source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electrical

I was looking at some second order questions on the internet and occasionally I see people introducing a second voltage source divided by "s". They also divide the capacitor by "s" and multiply the inductor by "s". I'm not quite sure how it works. I have taken a look in my textbook and haven't found anything regarding it, so I would love some input on what method this is.

Here's an example of what I mean:
[image]

Thanks, I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is Laplace transform approach.  Makes it an algebra problem and you can solve for steady state as well as transient response.  Start reading [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/Laplace_Transform#Laplace_Transform). Also, chapter 4 [of this](https://scholar.utc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1500&context=theses) is a relatively simple example circuit solved with Laplace.

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you very much!